# How can I modify a row directly on TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have this code :

```
...
var items:[String] = []

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
    return true
} 
....
```

And this function to add Update or Delete when swipe a row :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let update = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Update") { action, index in
        print("Updated")

        // I NEED THE CODE HERE TO MODIFY THIS ROW

    }

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete") { action, index in
        print("Deleted")

        self.items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.tblRefresh.reloadData()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.items, forKey: "items")
    }
    return [delete, update]
}
```

My application is a To Do List and look this :

[image: ToDoList]

I need the code to modify a selected row (in this example the selected row have "eggs" as a value) and auto save it when user press RETURN, no need to confirm update.

Delete button is work fine !

Answer (score 0):

Modify the data source (`self.items`) and then call `tableView. reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])`.